# FusionCharts - Div over the chart

Tags: php, css, flash, z-index, fusioncharts

I have many reports with FusionChart and I want to put an `div` with some loading message over it, but the div always stay under the flash object event using `z-index`!

Anyone already got rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<embed>` you need  `wmode="transparent"` and `<object>` elemebnt, you need to have `<param name="wmode" value="transparent"> </param>`.

It has to be in both to work, then hopefully it'll work as you want :)

Answer (score 1):

For FusionChart you could call addParam method

```
var chart = new FusionCharts("...", "ChartId", "300", "140");
chart.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=float+div+over+flash+object) reveals all...

According to several people [here](http://cssbeauty.com/skillshare/discussion/1419/display-div-on-top-of-flash-object/), you need to

> set your position on the div to relative, absolute or fixed and then set the z-index greater to the z-index of the flash content

then you need to

> set the wmode of the flash content to transparent

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, when instantiating class, you should add fifth parameter with boolean value, so the code looks like this:

```
$FC = new FusionCharts("Pie3D",$chartwidth,$chartheight,'',1);
```

From [fusion chart documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/guide-for-web-developers/fusioncharts-php-class/Functions.html) has been explained clearly.